# VS2022 Server Explorer and SSMS yield different query results

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2022, nullreferenceexception, json-query

I have a SQl Server query defined as follows:

```
SELECT      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY p.SKU) AS Id,
            p.Id AS ProductId,
            p.SKU, 
            'ImageURL' AS ImageURL,
            p.Name AS ProductName,
            p.FullDescription AS Description,
            p.Price,
            p.ProductCost,
            p.StockQuantity,
            JSON_QUERY(stuff((select ',"' + STRING_ESCAPE(Name, 'json') + '"'
               FROM dbo.Product_ProductTag_Mapping ptm
               INNER JOIN dbo.ProductTag pt
                  ON pt.Id = ptm.ProductTag_Id
               WHERE ptm.Product_Id = p.Id
               for xml path(''), type
               ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '[') + ']') Tags,
            JSON_QUERY(stuff((select ',"' + STRING_ESCAPE(Name, 'json') + '"'
               FROM dbo.Product_Category_Mapping pcm
               INNER JOIN dbo.Category ca
                  ON ca.Id = pcm.CategoryId
               WHERE pcm.ProductId = p.Id
               for xml path(''), type
               ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '[') + ']') Categories
                
FROM           dbo.Product AS p WITH (NOLOCK)
                INNER JOIN
                        dbo.Product_Category_Mapping AS pcmo WITH (NOLOCK) ON p.Id = pcmo.ProductId
                INNER JOIN
                        dbo.Product_Picture_Mapping AS ppm WITH (NOLOCK) ON p.Id = ppm.ProductId
WHERE        (p.Published = 1 AND p.StockQuantity > 0 AND p.Price > 0 AND p.IsGiftCard = 0
            -- This is for duplicate records in testing
            AND( p.Id IN (SELECT DISTINCT MIN(Id) FROM dbo.Product GROUP BY SKU) ))
```

When I run the query in SSMS, the column tags returns all nulls.
When I run the query in VS2022 Server Explorer the column tags displays the proper json string:

```
["topaz","peridot","emerald","silver","pierced"]
```

Both display categories as:

```
["Necklaces"]
```

Why the discrepancy. I believe this is why I'm getting a NullReferenceException in EFCore???

Any suggestions?

Abbott

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to the very same database? It seems rather unlikely that the exact same query would lead to different results, even if executed from different clients ...

Comment: If you suspect your query results are not correct, the first thing you do, irrespective of anything else, is remove the `nolock` hints which absolutely can yield unpredictable resutls. Do you know why you are using `read uncommitted` isolation?

Comment: Aside... the `WITH (NOLOCK)` hint is not a go faster button, it's an "I don't care if my results are messed up due to incomplete transactions that could even get rolled back later on" button.

Answer (score 0):

I went back and saw that the db I was testing against waws different.
Uggh. As usual, operator error.
Thanks
Abbott